# xdebug profiler output strange results

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm using xdebug to profile some PHP code on Windows and using WinCacheGrind/Webgrind to analyse the output, but I'm getting some strange results. Specifically, the total cumulative time for a single method is greater than 100%! How is it possible that more time is spent executing this function's code and all the functions that it calls than the total time it took to execute the whole script? What am I missing here?

Comment: Wondered that myself sometime, maybe it has to do with rounding or recursion. The output still was clear enough to distinguish bottlenecks, so never bothered to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use [XHGui](https://github.com/preinheimer/xhprof) instead of xdebug. XHGui is a nice enhancement to XHProf that Facebook built to help them profile their PHP code.

One of the best parts of XHGui, besides being able to compare executions, is the "hardest hit" tab. [Here is a good write up on how to use it](http://phpadvent.org/2010/profiling-with-xhgui-by-paul-reinheimer).

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that the function is in some way recursive.  If call 1 two function foo is in the stack trace for call 2 to function to then the total time for call 1 will include the time spent in call 2.  The total time spent in function foo will double count the time for call 2.